# What is raw interface in javascript DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom, interface

As far as I know javascript does't support multi inheritance, but it can be circumvented by using mixin. In [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/#Properties) of `Element` it says

> It implements the properties of ParentNode, ChildNode, NonDocumentTypeChildNode, and Animatable.

the same MDN doc says `ParentNode` is [mixin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode) and `ChildNode` is '[raw interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode)', I wonder what is 'raw interface'? I googled it but can't find any solid reference.

Comment: It says it right after that: "no object of this type can be created". It's like an abstract class in other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A raw interface is like a PHP interface, and similar to a C++ abstract base class.

These are classes that define methods, but don't provide their own implementations, so you can't create instances of the class. The methods are required to be implemented by subclasses. The interface exists for the purpose of specifying the common behavior of these methods.

Alternatively, they may provide implementations of the methods, but these implementations depend on other methods that have to be provided by the subclass.

In this case, the `ChildNode` interface is implemented by various types that can serve as children of other nodes: `Element`, `DocumentType`, and `CharacterData`.

Another example of a raw interface in many languages is iterable objects. A common interface allows applications to loop through the elements of these objects in a standard way. But each class will have different ways of storing its elements and getting the next element in sequence. This is all hidden behind the interface.

Comment: Thanks but why don't they just make `ChildNode` a mixin just like `ParentNode`?

Comment: A mixin is for adding functions to other classes. The mixin contains an independent implementation of its functions, it doesn't require the subclass to provide the implementation.